# Is it possible to use a list as a pattern when searching for matches?

Tags: c#, forms

I basically have criminals with different variables that are added to a report and it looks something like this:

```
reports.Add(new Report(tbxCriminalSuspicion.Text, 
   (new Criminal(Ordformatering(tbxName.Text), Ordformatering(tbxSex.Text), int.Parse(tbxAge.Text),
   double.Parse(tbxHeight.Text), Ordformatering(tbxHairColor.Text)))));
```

Then I create another string that I want to use to search between the criminals. You type into a textbox and it is placed into a list by:

```
string allSearchWords = tbxSearchWords.text;
List<string> splitSearchWords = new List<string>();
allSearchWords = allSearchWords.Replace(" ", "");
splitSearchWords = allSearchWords.Split(',').ToList();
```

Now I've got a list of words and I'm able to search my criminals via:

```
splitSearchWords.All((criminal).Contains);
```

However, in the case of the situation looking as:

Criminal 1: 18 years old, 176 cm

Criminal 2: 34 years old, 180 cm

Both criminals will show up in the Listbox even though only one is 18 years old. In other words, is it possible to search for an exact match using a list as a pattern? Can attach some code.

```
List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
List<string> splitSearchWords = new List<string>();

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbxLista.Items.Clear();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbxSearchWords.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vänligen fyll i dina sökord innan du söker enligt \"Sökord, sökord, sökord, ...\"",
                        "Felinmatning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                     //Just a check so that the searchbox isn't empty!!!!
            }

            else
            {
                string allSearchWords = tbxSearchWords.Text;
                allSearshWords = allSearshWords.Replace(" ", "");
                splitSearchWords = allSearchWords.Split(',').ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < reports.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(ContainsSearchWord(reports[i].GetData(), splitSearchWords))
                    {
                        lbxLista.Items.Add(reports[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool ContainsSearchWord(string stringToTest, List<string> searchedWords)
        {
            return searchedWords.All((stringToTest).Contains);
        }
```

The Classes, Report and Criminal:

```
class Report
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "" + criminal.criminalName + " " + criminal.criminalSex +
                " " + criminal.criminalAge + " " +
                criminal.criminalHeight + " " + criminal.criminalHairColor;
        }
    }

class Criminal
    {
        private string privatCriminalName;
        private string privatCriminalSex;
        private int privatCriminalAge;
        private double privatCriminalHeight;
        private string privatCriminalHairColor;

        public Criminal(string mCriminalName, string mCriminalSex,
            int mCriminalAge, double mCriminalHeight, string mCriminalHeightColor)
        {
            this.criminalName = mCriminalName;
            this.criminalSex = mCriminalSex;
            this.criminalAge = mCriminalAge;
            this.criminalHeight = mCriminalHeight;
            this.criminalHairColor = mCriminalHeightColor;
        }
        //Then I have properties to access these from outside the class but removed due to being messy and lengthy in post.
    }
```

[Layout of the program, ANMÄLAN is where you enter to register a crime, SÖK is where you search for reports and SÖKRESULTAT is where the matching reports will shop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8KP0.png)

Pardon the long post, after +10 hours I'm just lost.

Comment: Pardon me, noticed for horrible that introduction was... Tried fixing it up now though.
It's a class (the criminal) within a class (the report) and I've created a ToString() for the Report that simply spits out all the data in one long string with a space in between every piece of data. I split the searchwords in the tbxSearchWords using commas

Comment: What format do you expect the user to type the search query in? Giving their age and height as just a number or including 'years old' and 'cm', respectively?

Comment: I expect someone to type for example, "170, female, speeding"
Then my goal is for it to search all reports for 170 (being height), then search those for female, and lastly speeding so the reports showing up in the listbox would all say those 3 specific things. But they could still be different ages and have different names (the criminals).
So by no means a smart system, quiet dumb but in my mind it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a string to test the pattern, you can use an array. This array would contain each of the traits and the crime as separate `string` values. This way, you can still use `Contains`, but it will individually test the strings, instead of their substrings.

```
public static bool ContainsSearchWord(string stringToTest, List<string> searchedWords) {
        return searchedWords.All((stringToTest.Split(' ')).Contains);
}
```

You don't even have to create a variable for this, just use `Split()` on what you already have.

Comment: Works like a charm, mind explaning?
I get that I import the report data with the "string string string string string..." format and this is then split into an array via every blank space? Confusion and fatigue is peaking

Comment: Simply putting it into an array forces it to match completely as it tests it against an "element" and not a "single string"? Sorry if I'm tedious, appreciate the answers and understanding.

Comment: Basically yes. Because the elements of a string are substrings in this case. Which include incomplete ones like 'Joh', for example. Elements of a string-array are full strings.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to search for an exact match using a list as a pattern?

Taking a bit of a stab in the dark here but if you have these strings:

```
criminals = new string[] {
  "Criminal 1: 18 years old, 176 cm",
  "Criminal 2: 34 years old, 180 cm"
}
```

And the user types this as their search term:

```
18,old
```

And you want to make sure the "18" doesn't match **18**0 in the height of Criminal 2, then you can use a regular expression:

```
var searchTerms = "18,old".Split(',').Select(s => $@"\b{s}\b").ToArray();


criminals.Where(c => searchTerms.All(st => Regex.IsMatch(c, st)));
```

This will return only criminal where the string matches all the regular expressions.

Critically, your `searchTerms` have become an array like:

```
new string[] { @"\b18\b", @"\bold\b" };
```

The `\b` means "word boundary" - a zero-width character between a "non word character" like a space, punctuation, end/start of string etc, and the word character you're looking for

Thus `\b18\b` will match "he is **18** years old" and "it is 18", but it will not match "it is 180 years old", nor "it is 218 years old" etc

---

If you want to do it without regex, you could split the criminal strings on space:

```
var searchTerms = "18,old".Split(',')

criminals.Where(c => { 
  var words = c.Split(); 
  return searchTerms.All(st => words.Contains(st)); 
} );
```

but it's not so sophisticated; it would have `old,` in the `words`, so my search term above of `old` wouldn't find a match.. If you wanted to counter that, you'd have to split on more stuff (punctuation etc) than just space..

---

Now, about that case sensitivity...